# How do I loop background video and remove controls and still keep my randomized background video?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, background

So I'm making my videos my backgrounds and the script refreshes on load or update.

Whenever I start up my website I can see the controls for the video for less than a second then the video plays.

**How can I remove that and make my video loop?**

Also when you `zoom out` on the page once the video ends you can see the controls. I'll include a screenshot at the bottom.

If needed I can provide a link to my website where you can see what I'm talking about. Just let me know.

```css
.video-background {
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -100;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.video-foreground,
.video-background iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
#vidtop-content {
 top: 0;
 color: #fff;
}
.vid-info { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; width: 33%; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3); color: #fff; padding: 1rem; font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
.vid-info h1 { font-size: 2rem; font-weight: 700; margin-top: 0; line-height: 1.2; }
.vid-info a { display: block; color: #fff; text-decoration: none; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); transition: .6s background; border-bottom: none; margin: 1rem auto; text-align: center; }
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .video-foreground { height: 300%; top: -100%; }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .video-foreground { width: 300%; left: -100%; }
}
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
.vid-info { width: 50%; padding: .5rem; }
.vid-info h1 { margin-bottom: .2rem; }
}
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
.vid-info .acronym { display: none; }
}
```

```html
     <script>
        var videos = ["./Videos/1.mp4", "./Videos/2.mp4", "./Videos/3.mp4", "./Videos/4.mp4"];
        window.onload = function () {
            var playerDiv = document.getElementById("random_player");
            var player = document.createElement("IFRAME");
            var randomVideoUrl = videos[Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length)];
            player.setAttribute('width', '100%');
            player.setAttribute('height', '100%');
            player.setAttribute('src', randomVideoUrl);
            playerDiv.appendChild(player);
        };
    </script>
    
    <div class="video-background">
    <div class="video-foreground">
    <div id="random_player" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HStja.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove controls:

```
player.controls = false;
```

Play in loop:

```
player.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
}, false);

player.play();
```

But I see you're loading it inside an **iframe**. Why is that? Why don't you simply use the **video** HTML element? It would be something like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var playerDiv = document.getElementById('random_player');
    var player = document.createElement('video');
    var sourceVideo = document.createElement('source');
    var randomVideoUrl = videos[Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length)];
    player.setAttribute('width', '100%');
    player.setAttribute('height', '100%');
    sourceVideo.setAttribute('src', randomVideoUrl);
    playerDiv.appendChild(player);
    player.appendChild(sourceVideo);
    player.controls = false;
    player.addEventListener('ended', function () {
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.play();
    }, false);
    player.play();
};
```

Comment: I tried using what you sent me and it worked but it broke my buttons and now they won't take me to the link that was set and use the animations when hovering over. Do you know what's causing this?

Comment: Nevermind I deleted a few things in my css and it worked again. Thank you for your help.